# Is it possible to speculate on the completion of an adder from the first row?

Tags: cpu, adder, homebrew-cpu

I've seen speculative adders that take an extra clock cycle something on the order of once in 10^5 additions.  Often [papers on speculative adders](http://ijiet.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/16011.pdf) claim to need the information from stage 1 and stage `n`, but always error check entirely from stage `n`.  See page 73, where `G` from stage 1 of bits 1, 3, 5, and 7 are needed; but on page 74, the error check uses `G` from stage 2 of bit 3, and stage 3 of bits 5 and 7.

If a carry is propagated, it will change `G=0` at stage 1 to `G=1` at subsequent stages.

This speculator checks if `G=1` at the lower half even bits (1, 3, 5, 7…yes, starting from 0) and `P=1` from those bits + `n/2` for `n` bit length (e.g. +16 for 32-bit).  If any such pair are both `1`, it detects the computation is in error and muxes the final stage back in.

Just curious why it's like that.

The 64-bit speculative adder decreases delay by 24% when it predicts properly, and increases the delay by 66% when it errors.  Most papers claim error mandates an additional clock cycle; from what I see, an error requires an additional 1.18 clock cycles.

Comment: *10^-5* or *10^+5*?

Comment: Got mixed up.  It's usually listed as happening with frequency 10^-5 (a fancy way of saying 1 in 10^5 I guess).